# Sorting object list in Java - String object containing Decimal Number

Tags: java, arrays

I have numbers from 3.1 - 3.20. Which is set of question numbers as shown below

```
List<Line> liner = new ArrayList<>();
for(int counter = 0; counter < rpkKode.size(); counter++) {
    Line linerObj = new Line();
    linerObj.setQuestionNmbr(rpkKode.get(counter).getQuestionNumber());
    liner.add(linerObj);
}
```

When I print it prints as following:
3.1, 3.11, 3.12, ... 3.19, 3.2, 3.20, 3.3, 3.4

I want to print it sequence wise. Can i do any operations (may be using third party), so that I can sort an object to 3.1 to 3.20 in serial order?

I could not convert it into Double as i need to display it on screen using JSTL and it is get issues, while handling 1.10, 1.20 or 1.200 and lots of Jquery issues related to validations on same.

Comment: you could use the `List#sort` function and write your own comperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used NaturalOrderComparator.java -- Perform 'natural order' comparisons of strings in Java.

File by Copyright (C) 2003 by Pierre-Luc Paour. Link (http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/naomi/trunk/de.uni_mannheim.informatik.swt.naomi.contentcomparator/src/de/uni_mannheim/informatik/swt/naomi/contentcomparator/NaturalOrderComparator.java)

Following code will sort the numbers as expected

```
Map<String, Class> questionsMap = new TreeMap<>(new NaturalNumberComparator());
```

If any one have better solution kindly do share.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Comparable interface in your `Line` class:

```
public class Line implements Comparable<Line> {

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Line o){
        // if question number is type of Integer
        return Integer.compare(this.getQuestionNumber(), o.getQuestionNumber());
    }
}
```

And after that you could use `Collections.sort(liner);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Collections.sort(objects, comparator)
If default comparators don't work for you you can make custom comparator to sort the objects in any order and any rules you want.

Answer (score 0):

You your own comparator and compare the question numbers using the numbers after the decimal.

Comment: what if there will be `[3.20, 4.10, 3.30]` ?

Comment: You your comparator to check the integral part first and then go for decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with unique String, you can use TreeSet as well.

**Let's consider your Line class as below:**

```
public class Line implements Comparable<Line> {

    String questionNo;

    public Line(String questionNo) {
        super();
        this.questionNo = questionNo;
    }

    public String getQuestionNo() {
        return questionNo;
    }
    public void setQuestionNo(String questionNo) {
        this.questionNo = questionNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Line obj){

        String splitted1[] = this.getQuestionNo().split("\\.");
        String splitted2[] = obj.getQuestionNo().split("\\.");

        if(Integer.parseInt(splitted2[0]) > Integer.parseInt(splitted1[0])) {
            return -1;
        } 

        if(splitted1.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if(splitted2.length == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        return this.getQuestionNo().compareTo(obj.getQuestionNo());
    }
}
```

Now try,

```
Set<Line> ts = new TreeSet<Line>();
ts.add(new Line("3.1"));
ts.add(new Line("3.11"));
ts.add(new Line("3.12"));
ts.add(new Line("3.19"));
ts.add(new Line("3.2"));
ts.add(new Line("3"));
ts.add(new Line("3.20"));
ts.add(new Line("3.3"));
ts.add(new Line("3.4"));

for (Line line : ts) {
    System.out.println(line.getQuestionNo());
}
```

I did it in hurry. If you find any issue, let me know.

Comment: This will gives 3.11,3.12,3.19,3.2,3.20,3.3,3.4  , again does not solve the problem

Comment: I get your question wrong first time. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The update gives: 3
3.1,
3.11,
3.12,
3.19,
3.2,
3.20,
3.3,
3.4. No. It is not solution